# SAPUI5 List binding with filtered data in XML view

Tags: data-binding, sapui5, jsonmodel

I hope you are doing well

Currently i'm trying to bind a filtered data to a list control in xml view in the oninit event of the controller the odata service url is like this

http://mikmo.mylocalhost.com/MIKMOWCFDataService.svc/view_VendorGroup?$filter=VendorID%20eq%201

i used the code below

```
var sListURI = "http://mikmo.mylocalhost.com/MIKMOWCFDataService.svc";
        var oListModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sListURI, false);
        var oListModelJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oListModel.oHeaders = {
            "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",
            "MaxDataServiceVersion": "2.0"
        };
        oListModel.read("/view_VendorGroup", null, ["$filter=VendorID eq " + window.VendorID], null, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oListModelJson.setData(oData);
            oListModelJson.loadData(oData);

        }, null);

        //oListModelJson.bindList(sPath, [oContext], [aSorters], [aFilters], [mParameters])
        oListModelJson.attachRequestCompleted(function(oData, oEvent) {

        });
        myList.setModel(oListModelJson, "VendorGroups");
```

and in the XML view

```
<List growing="true" growingThreshold="100" headerText="{i18n&gt;businessareas}" id="lstVendorGroups">
                            <items>
                                <!--<ObjectListItem title="{VendorGroups>GroupName}" type="Active" press=".onItemSelected" />  -->
                                <StandardListItem id="stListItem" />
                            </items>
                        </List>
```

What i need to know is how to bind the list items in the attachRequestCompleted method with the data
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the aggregation 'items' of the sap.m.List.
I would modify the following things in your code:

1. Read method of oDataModel: Once you do a read operation using oDataModel, you get the success handler where you are setting the data in your local JSON Model. The code line :`oListModelJson.loadData(oData);` is not required as the previous line of code is : `oListModelJson.setData(oData);` - is already setting the data to your local JSON Model.
2. AttachRequestCompleted of JSON Model: I would not use this method as it is used when you are loading data ( via AJAX call) directly to JSON Model. But here as you are using oData Model to fetch, is it not required. So I will delete the handler.
3. In Your XML views, you need to tell sap.m.List, the path of where your array of Objects is present. Considering that you have applied filters, your JSON model will contain data starting with 'results' keyword. Please paste your JSON Model data if below code doesn't help:

Code in XML:

```
<List growing="true" growingThreshold="100" headerText="{i18n&gt;businessareas}" id="lstVendorGroups" items="{VendorGroups>/results}">
                            <items>
                                <!--<ObjectListItem title="{VendorGroups>GroupName}" type="Active" press=".onItemSelected" />  -->
                                <StandardListItem id="stListItem" />
                            </items>
                        </List>
```

Code in Controller after my modifications:

```
var sListURI = "http://mikmo.mylocalhost.com/MIKMOWCFDataService.svc";
        var oListModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sListURI, false);
        var oListModelJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oListModel.oHeaders = {
            "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",
            "MaxDataServiceVersion": "2.0"
        };
        oListModel.read("/view_VendorGroup", null, ["$filter=VendorID eq " + window.VendorID], null, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oListModelJson.setData(oData);
           // oListModelJson.loadData(oData);

        }, null);

        //oListModelJson.bindList(sPath, [oContext], [aSorters], [aFilters], [mParameters])
        //oListModelJson.attachRequestCompleted(function(oData, oEvent) {
        //
        //});
        this.byId('lstVendorGroups').setModel(oListModelJson, "VendorGroups");
```

Comment: Dear Rahul thanks for your reply i updated the code as you suggested but still no luck however when i use console.log for the JSONMODEL i got the exact filtered result but there is no data bound to the control here is the result of the JSONMODEL log results
:
Array[3]
0
:
Object
GroupName
:
"Abortion Policy/Pro-Abortion Rights"
VendorGroupID
:
1
VendorID
:
1
__metadata
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object

Comment: Can you tell me how have you fetched myList in Controller code ? Also, did you update your XML code?

Comment: I've updated my controller code: please use: `this.byId('lstVendorGroups').setModel(oListModelJson, "VendorGroups"); ` where `myList.setModel(oListModelJson, "VendorGroups");` was used